# How do I Access Response Header in Http Request

Tags: asp-classic, http-headers, httprequest

I'm making a call to an external API. The data it returns, annoyingly, is in the header (the text response is empty).

How do I access the header of the response?

This is what I'm trying:

```
    Dim  httpRequest, postResponse
    Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    httpRequest.Open "POST", "http://www.api.com", False, "un", "pw"
    httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", len(jsondata)
    httpRequest.Send data
    if httpRequest.status = 200 then
        response.write httpRequest.getResponseHeader
        response.write httpRequest.ResponseText
    end if
    Set httpRequest = nothing
```

But it gives me:

```
    msxml3.dll error '80072f76'

    The requested header was not found
```

And a bonus question: I just noticed the "XML" part of "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" - am I using the right protocol? It's always worked for straight posts and gets until now.

Comment: aren't you missing which header you want to retrieve? aka `httpRequest.getResponseheader("server")` as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms765415(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the [response header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765415(v=vs.85).aspx) you want to retrieve:

```
response.write httpRequest.getResponseHeader("SomeHeaderName")
```

There's no just one response header. There could be many. You have the standard response headers such as `Content-Type` and you could also have custom headers.

> And a bonus question: I just noticed the "XML" part of
>   "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" - am I using the right protocol?

Yes, absolutely, that's the correct COM object to be used from a classic ASP application to send HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks Darin, that was just the answer I was looking for - much appreciated